# Difficulty Finding Input Field Using Selenium XPath in Python

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm currently learning Selenium automation and I'm trying to automate a simple task:

1. navigating to a webpage, (https://sri-gpt.github.io)
2. locating an input field,
3. entering text into it, and submitting the form.

To achieve this, I'm using Python and Selenium WebDriver.

Here's the code I've written:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://sri-gpt.github.io")

# Find the form field using its XPath
form_field = driver.find_element("xpath", '/html/body/flutter-view/flt-text-editing-host/form/input[1]')
form_field.send_keys("MyInput_123")

driver.quit()
```

However, when I execute this code, I encounter the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/flutter-view/flt-text-editing-host/form/input[1]"}
```

It seems that my `XPath` expression to locate the input field is incorrect. I've tried different variations, but none seem to work. Can anyone help me correct my XPath expression to successfully locate the input field on the webpage?

Additionally, if there are any best practices or alternative methods for locating elements using Selenium WebDriver, I'd appreciate any advice or suggestions.

```
Selenium version: 4.18.1
Python version: 3.10.12
Ubuntu version: 22.04 
Chrome version: 22.0.6261.128 (Official Build) (64-bit)
```

Thank you!

Comment: I set a breakpoint at the find_element command (breakpoint()) so that the driver remains open and I can test my code. There is a selenium extension which is supposed to help you with finding the right xpath, even recording tasks, but I always got back to my method. Developer tools of most browsers might be helpful.

Comment: @Dronakuul Thanks! I'm still learning Selenium and I obtained this `Xpath` from the Chrome `inspect-element` option. Can you kindly explain further  about the breakpoint part? I will try the extension meanwhile.

Comment: So, when you are developing your selenium automation, you probably just restart the script over and over. You have to wait (it depends on the length of your automation) only to see that in the end, you missed something in the xpath. When you insert the command "breakpoint()" before the line where you use the xpath, after running the script, you will get an interactive prompt hat this particular line of code, prefixed by "(pdb)" the python debugger. Especially in the beginning, there was much trial and error for me, and doing this interactively (with pdb) helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Use below xpath to type into textbox

```
//input[contains(@class, 'flt-text-editing')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use XPath or chropath chrome extension to find the exact element.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).